# C# Implement Transactional Rollback On A Method That Calls Another Method That SavesChanges() To The Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, rollback

How do I implement transactional rollback on `method1()` that calls another `method2()` that `SavesChanges()*` to the database?

I tried the implementation below but it keeps on inserting the record into the database.

I want the transaction to rollback as soon as an exception is thrown in `method2()`.

I know I'm able to do this in Java by using this annotation: `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)`

How do I achieve the same thing in C# ?

Kindly review the code below.

```
public void method1()
{
  using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
  try
    {
        mehtod2();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}

public void mehtod2()
{
    var user = new User();
    user.Id = 1;
    user.Name = "John Doe";
    _context.Add(user);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    throw new Exception("LET'S SAY AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE FOR SOME REASON");
}
```

Comment: Your implementation seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  My thinking exactly but it keeps committing to the database even after the exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you able to move the call to SaveChanges after the call to `method2`?

Comment: Do you happen to know if Multiple Active Result Sets(mars) is enabled.

Comment: @RossBush I don't think MARS is enabled. From my understanding, it is disabled by default unless I enable it in my connection string. Should I enable it? Trying it now...

Comment: @Jdslk - I just wanted to point out there is a warning about using savepoints and MARS in the official docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: @gunr2171 Kindly clarify, I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: @RossBush I've skimmed through the documentation. I get your point. This might even contain the solution I'm looking for -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#cross-context-transaction

Still reviewing.